# Analyzing whether the unit circle $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2=1\}$ is Jordan measurable - 3 different ways

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let $D$ be a bounded set and $C$ a rectangular cuboid with $D\subset C$. Let $P=\{C_i|i\in I\}$ be a partition of $C$.
In our script $D$ is Jordan-measurable if:

1. $D$ is Jordan-measurable  if and only if the indicator function $\chi_D$ is integrable on $C$.
   Then the Volume of $D$ is given by $F(D)=\int \limits_{C}^{}\chi_D$.
2. Its inner $F_i$ and outer $F_o$ volume are equal, with

$F_i(D):=\underset{P}{\text{sup}}\sum \limits_{\underset{i\in I}{C_i\subset D}} F(C_i)$

$F_o(D):=\underset{P}{\text{inf}}\sum \limits_{\underset{i\in I}{C_i\cap D\neq \emptyset}}F(C_i)$

3. A set $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a Jordan null set if it is Jordan-measurable and $F(D)=0$.
   $D$ is Jordan-measurable if and only if the boundary $\partial D$ is a Jordan null set.

Is the unit circle $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2=1\}$ Jordan-measurable?

1)
To calculte $\chi_S$ over a bounded set, one needs to continue the function over a cuboid $C$ with $S\subset C$.
In our case $C=[-1,1]^2$ ensures that $S\subset C$.

Using the Fubini theorem:

$$F(S)=\int \limits_C \chi_S=\int \limits_{[-1,1]\times [-1,1]}^{}\chi_S=\int \limits_{-1}^{1}\int \limits_{-1}^{1}\chi_S \, dy \, dx$$

The condition is that $(x,y)$ is on the unit-circle, so $y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

I don't know how to continue?

2)
I didn't want to just write "no idea" so here are some thoughts:

I know that $S$ has no inner points ( i proved that in another exercise), so I think that $C_i\not \subset S$ for every partition $P=\{C_i|i\in I\}$ of $C$.
So I'm not sure what $F_i(S)=\underset{P}{\text{sup}}\sum \limits_{\underset{i\in I}{C_i\subset S}} F(C_i)$ even means in this case.

A partition with $C_i\cap S\neq \emptyset$ is possible so
$F_o(S)=\underset{P}{\text{inf}}\sum \limits_{\underset{i\in I}{C_i\cap S\neq \emptyset}}F(C_i)$ would be a meaningful expression.

3. The boundary of the unit circle is $\partial S=S$. So I need to use the definition $1)$ or $2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline of the proof**

*For (1)*

Notice that for any $x \in [-1,1]$, $y \mapsto\chi_S(x,y)$ is a map defined and equal to $0$ on $[-1,1]$, except at the points $\{-\sqrt{1-x^2},\sqrt{1-x^2}\}$ where is is equal to $1$. Hence $\int_{-1}^1 \chi_S(x,y) dy = 0$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$ and $F(S)=0$ using Fubini as you mentioned.

*For (2)*

$F_i(S)=0$ as no rectangular cuboid is included in $S$.

Prove that $F_o(S)=0$ using rectangular cuboids with horizontal side lengths equal to $1/n$ and let $n \to \infty$.